# Pull out the specific data when the relation ship is many to many in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to ask about how to pull out the specific data (some columns) from the Laravel database

Here is my code :

**User Model :**

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Events')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Event Controller :**

```
public function showjson(){
    $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $events = DB::table('events')
            ->select(
                'id',
                'calendar_title as title',
                'startdate as start',
                'enddate as end',
                'calendar_color as backgroundColor',
                'calendar_color as borderColor')
            ->where('user_id',$user_id)
            ->get();
    $user=Auth::user();
    $eventData=$user->events;


    return $eventData;
}
```

I have already the relationship between this two, I can get the data through this :

```
$user = Auth::user();
$eventData = $user->events;
```

But I want to get specific columns by name, like in `select code` above.

Would that be another way that I can call the specific data and change the column name?

Comment: What is your desired result ?

Comment: For example, i want display in json only the calendar_title, calendar_des only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want display in json only the calendar_title, calendar_des only.

You can use `lists` to retrieve a list of column values, take a look at Database Query Builder **[Retrieving Results section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results)** :

```
$user->events->lists('calendar_title','calendar_des');
```

If you want to return Json format you can use **[toJson() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json)** :

```
$user->events->lists('calendar_title','calendar_des')->toJson();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this help me to get the specific data. But do you know how to get with the column name ? And can change it?

Comment: Hi, like for example i want `'{id' : 1, 'calendar_title': 'lunch'}'. Something like this